# Python Function Guessing Game Dictionaries

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a game, see (1), where the user inputs a 4 digit number, the number gets split separated into 4 items in a dictionary and then those are compared to a (a random 4 digit number) and they are told how many of their numbers are right compared to a, but not the position. I need to create a function to do this and was thinking of something like, see (2). Thanks

(1)

```
import random
b = list(input("input a four digit number: "))
b1 = b[0]
b2 = b[1]
b3 = b[2]
b4 = b[3]
b = {1:int(b1), 2:int(b2), 3:int(b3), 4:int(b4)}
a1 = random.randint(0,9)
a2 = random.randint(0,9)
a3 = random.randint(0,9)
a4 = random.randint(0,9)
a = {1:int(a1), 2:int(a2), 3:int(a3), 4:int(a4)}
```

(2)

```
def b_in_a():
    for b[i] in a:
        x += 1
```

Edit: sorry, the problem is, I don't know how to create a function that effectivley does this. Other methods I tried ended up doing funky things like always adding to 16 and have no idea why. I can post the whole code I have here if that will help. The stuff I removed is mainly messages and such.

Comment: And the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> num1 = list(map(int, list(input("Input 4-digit number:"))))
Input 4-digit number:1234
>>> num1
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> num2 = [randint(0, 9), randint(0, 9), randint(0, 9), randint(0, 9)]
>>> num2
[2, 4, 8, 4]
>>> count = 0
>>> for i in range(4):
...     if num1[i] == num2[i]:
...         count += 1
...
>>> count
1
```